# the equivalent struts 2 tags for the following nested tags <nested:root>

Tags: struts2

We are migrating struts 1 applications to struts 2.please help me with getting the equivalent struts 2 tags for the following nested tags.

```
<nested:equal property="dispatch" value="duplicateView">    
    <body>

    </body>
</nested:equal> 

<nested:equal property="dispatch" value="updateSuccess">    
    <body>
</nested:equal> 
<nested:notEqual property="dispatch" value="updateSuccess">     
    <body> 
</nested:notEqual>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The nested tags are just for accessing a bean hierarchy, right? You just need to set a value using `<s:set>` and access the properties as normal.

If the bean hierarchy is known you can just access it directly via normal OGNL syntax, e.g.,

```
%{whateverRootBeanIs.dispatch.duplicateView}
```